# Generate DataMatrix 2D Code (ECC 200)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, barcode, datamatrix

I need to create a DataMatrix code in Swift and I have only found a solution with the help of the ZXingObjc library. https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC

Is there any other way to do this? I do also use RSBarcodes_Swift (https://github.com/yeahdongcn/RSBarcodes_Swift), which is currently not supporting DataMatrix and also the CIFilter is not able to create DataMatrix images.

Thank you!
Boris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the ZXingObjc library with Swift.  I just accessed the Objective-C libraries via a ObjC-Swift bridging header file.  It worked really well.

Only downside for me was the amount of other barcode symbologies supported in the ZXingObjC library.  When you install ZXingObjc into your Swift Workspace via a dependency tool like CocoaPod, you get a lot of code you don't need.

Comment: Thank you! I now did the same, and it did work pretty well. As you said, there is a lot of code now in my project that I do not need, but I really have not found any other solution.